# Resampling with Pandas spline gives strange results. Do I misunderstand, even though the time matches?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I take my dataframe, which is in seconds, and resample it over a period of every n seconds, to properly align all values with even spacing.

The seconds are parsed correctly, but the output results are strange, so maybe I'm completely misunderstanding what exactly is being splined over?

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "time": [0., 1.1, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 7.7, 9.9, 10.0],
            "floats": [0., 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.0],
            "ints": [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        }
    )

df["time"]=pd.to_timedelta(df["time"],unit="s")

df.set_index("time",inplace=True)
df_interpolated = df.resample("2s").interpolate("spline", order=1)

print("Input:")
print(df)

print("Output:")
print(df_interpolated)

f_data_int = interp1d(df.index.astype(int), df["ints"])
interpolated_int = f_data_int(df_interpolated.index.astype(int))

f_data_float = interp1d(df.index.astype(int), df["floats"])
interpolated_float = f_data_float(df_interpolated.index.astype(int))

df_fixed = df_interpolated.copy()

df_fixed["floats"] = interpolated_float
df_fixed["ints"] = interpolated_int#.astype(int)
print("Expected:")
print(df_fixed.round(2))
```

Gives

```
Input:
                        floats  ints
time                                
0 days 00:00:00            0.0     0
0 days 00:00:01.100000     0.1     1
0 days 00:00:03.300000     0.2     1
0 days 00:00:04.400000     0.3     1
0 days 00:00:05.500000     0.4     1
0 days 00:00:07.700000     0.3     0
0 days 00:00:09.900000     0.2     0
0 days 00:00:10            0.0     1


Output:
                 floats  ints
time                         
0 days 00:00:00     0.0   0.0
0 days 00:00:02     0.0   0.2
0 days 00:00:04     0.0   0.4
0 days 00:00:06     0.0   0.6
0 days 00:00:08     0.0   0.8
0 days 00:00:10     0.0   1.0


Expected:
                 floats  ints
time                         
0 days 00:00:00    0.00  0.00
0 days 00:00:02    0.14  1.00
0 days 00:00:04    0.26  1.00
0 days 00:00:06    0.38  0.77
0 days 00:00:08    0.29  0.00
0 days 00:00:10    0.00  1.00
```

So where did my values go in the output?

Comment: It looks like `resample().interpolate()` is indeed `reindex()` with the new times and interpolate. I'm not sure if it's the intended behavior by the devs or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you resample, you lose a lot of data that does not fit the 2s timestep. Therefore, you can't use it for the interpolation.

```py
import datetime

# upsample with very small steps
# specify interpolation rule if the date does not fit to the timedelta pattern 
# (for example, if your time is like 0.111 -- not a multiple of 0.1)
timedelta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=0.1)
# upsample and interpolate
df_interpolated = df.resample(timedelta, convention='end').interpolate("spline", order=1)
# resample to keep points only at 2s intervals. We don't have missing values, so
# None can be filled out by any method
df_interpolated = df_interpolated.resample('2s').asfreq()
```